# What do you call a person who uses the required amount of resources?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

A person who does work with the maximum care in order to avoid waste.

Example: A wife who cooks only for the number of guests invited at that moment.

Comment: This sounds like a resourceful person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that would be [***frugal***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/frugal).

> 1 Sparing or economical as regards money or food:
>   *I’m a bit too frugal to splash out on designer clothes*
>
> 1.1 Simple and plain and costing little:
>   *a frugal meal*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/frugal

Answer (score 0):

[Thrifty](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Thrifty) might fit the bill.

**thrifty**: wisely economical; careful or diligent in the way of resources